# How to create plist for Uinavigation tableview

Tags: iphone, plist

Am having the task like in UITableView, In root view i have country list if selected the country it should navigate to next view display the state list of that country, if i select state it should navigate and displays the cities, if i select city need displays a popular areas and then hospitals list in that area how do i create plist for that. Then how shall i get value from that plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can create PList as follows:

add independent rows for each country. Each row set value type as array. And values add multiple rows & put state and for value again put data type as Array. And put respective cities into that.

It will work for you then.

there are more ways to do it but in this case you'll get all data in a single dictionary and you can maintain your table easily using it.